# error spark-shell, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm trying to connect a spark-shell amazon hadoop, but I esart all the time giving the following error and do not know how to fix it or configure what is missing.

`spark.yarn.jars`, `spark.yarn.archive`

```
spark-shell --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/08/12 07:47:26 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
16/08/12 07:47:28 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
```

Thx!!!

**Error1**

I'm trying to run a SQL query, something totally simple as:

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT col1 FROM tabl1 limit 10")
sqlDF.show()
```

> WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

**Error2**

Then I try to run a script scala, something simple collected in:
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2D93GZRHU3TES/Using-Spark-SQL-for-ETL

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import java.util.HashMap


var ddbConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "tableDynamoDB")
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.write.percent", "0.5")
ddbConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")
ddbConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")


var genreRatingsCount = sqlContext.sql("SELECT col1 FROM table1 LIMIT 1")

var ddbInsertFormattedRDD = genreRatingsCount.map(a => {
var ddbMap = new HashMap[String, AttributeValue]()

var col1 = new AttributeValue()
col1.setS(a.get(0).toString)
ddbMap.put("col1", col1)

var item = new DynamoDBItemWritable()
item.setItem(ddbMap)

(new Text(""), item)
}
)

ddbInsertFormattedRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(ddbConf)
```

> scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object InterfaceAudience
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1502)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1500)
>     at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)

Comment: seems like its warning not error. What is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spark UI not started, tried to start spark shell and also check sparkUI `localhost:4040` running correctly.